# Asp.net c# sql server read binary sql field data in chunk

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I my database we have a varbinary field which store file content in byte.

As the file is big and reading all content in one shot leads to time-out so I want to read that data in chunk like we have write function in sql to write data using chunk.

Please suggest any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the `FILESTREAM` data type?

More info about how to do it http://weblogs.asp.net/aghausman/archive/2009/03/16/saving-and-retrieving-file-using-filestream-sql-server-2008.aspx

Answer (score 1):

To do that via a simple `SELECT ...`, you can drop to ADO.NET, i.e. `ExecuteReader`, specifying the `CommandBehaviour.SequentialAccess` flag. Now you can call *repeatedly* the [`GetBytes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idatarecord.getbytes.aspx) method to read **sequential** chunks into a buffer. For example:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[8040];
int bytes;
long offset = 0;
while((bytes = (int)reader.GetBytes(col, offset, buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) >0) {
    // TODO: do something with `bytes` bytes from `buffer`
    offset += bytes;
}
```